# AttributeError: 'FFmpegWriter' object has no attribute '_proc'

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I have some problem which i cannot find answer to. After installing scikit-video and FFmpeg i got this error:

AttributeError: 'FFmpegWriter' object has no attribute '_proc'

can you help me to find solution to this.

```
from skvideo.io import FFmpegWriter

def main():
    ...
    video_writer = FFmpegWriter('video.mp4')
    ...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Already tried to install pyaudio, reinstall FFmpeg and skvideo and install different versions of packages. Does not help at all.

Edit: an example of the full traceback resulting from `/skvideo/io/abstract.py` is below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "run_modules.py", line 93, in <module>
    Pipeline.create_videos(video_attr, args.output_path, args.padded)
File "/home/leuko/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skvideo/io/abstract.py", line 474, in close
    if self._proc is None:  # pragma: no cover
AttributeError: 'FFmpegWriter' object has no attribute '_proc'
```

Comment: always show full error message (Trackback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this issue, and found that `FFmpegWriter` was actually masking another error.  My code was roughly like this:

```
    with FFmpegWriter('/tmp/tmp.webm') as writer:
        for frame in frames:
            <code to generate out>
            writer.writeFrame(out)
```

The code block before `writer.writeFrame` was raising an error, but I didn't see that because I didn't look at the full stack trace.  I couldn't figure out why `FFmpegWriter` was throwing this error, but it made sense once I realized I wasn't actually writing any frames but was then trying to close the writer.